# backgrounds and wallpapers RHEL CentOS 7 Gnome3

Tags: gnome3, wallpaper

- Any user logged in, they can right click on desktop and get *Change Background*
- This takes you to the global *Settings* panel with *Background* chosen
- Here it shows *Background* and *Lock Screen*
- Under *Background* it then allows for **Wallpapers**, **Pictures**, **Colors**.

Problem I have is *Pictures* works but it shows any .jpg file under `$HOME/` and **not** under `$HOME/Pictures`.  And this obviously makes for a messy home directory if you want a many different pics to choose from, and I don't want N users having N copies of the same pics eating up disk space; I want all background pics/wallpapers in one location.

Under **Wallpapers** it seems it is limited to 16, and they are those that come pre-installed located in `/usr/share/backgrounds/gnome/`.  I have tried adding extras and they do not show up and Wallpaper choices; if I remove what is there then they do not show up; and only those originals file names like *Fabric.jpg* or *Road.jpg* work to show up in the menu.  If I overwrite those original 16 file names with different pics then those new pics show up as menu choices in Background-Wallpapers.  Also if you right click on any picture and choose *Set as Wallpaper* that seems to create a `$HOME/Wallpapers` folder but this is a per-user thing.

I have many gnome related items installed, here are what I think are relevant; this installed in CentOS-7.6.1810:

```
gnome-desktop3-3.28.2-2.el7.x86_64  
gnome-themes-standard-3.28-2.el7.x86_64
gnome-backgrounds-3.28.0-1.el7.noarch
gnome-menus-3.13.3-3.el7.x86_64
```

**My goal** is to allow all users, in a work type environment, to be able to choose from a global set of nice wallpapers or pics **stored in one location** to change their desktop background to.  **It has to be simple** because as far as anyone should have to go and as far as I am willing to tell anyone is: *right click on desktop and choose change background.* And then they can  see and choose from 5, 20, or 100 pics to choose from.  Is this possible?

Comment: there are also some shortcomings under the basic solid color choices: only 15 pre-defined,  and you cannot set your own custom color

Comment: I gave up on getting the normal Gnome desktop settings to do what I wanted (on Ubuntu 18.04); I installed `gnome-tweaks` instead, which made it simple although not as graphically pretty for the selection.

Answer (score 1):

try gnome-tweaks? ("tweaks") still exploring all it adds, and why it does not come by default (though is trivial to add)

I was surprised too that the default centOS DE does not allow you to pick a folder for desktop backgrounds? it is only ~/Pictures, no subdirs.

per Ubuntu docs, ~/Pictures "because this is where most photo management applications store [pictures]"

Answer (score 0):

CentOS default backgrounds are stored under `/usr/share/backgrounds/c8/default/standard/`

```
c8-hue-0.png  c8-hue-1.png  c8-hue-2.png  c8-hue-3.png  c8-hue-4.png
c8-hue-5.png  c8-hue-6.png  c8-hue-7.png  c8-hue-8.png  c8-hue-9.png  c8.png
```

You can manipulate this somewhat using "gsettings", for example:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/c8/default-hue-7.xml'
```